# Unity on Android error: Unable to initialize the Unity Engine Gfx API

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Bulding an application for Android on Unity i get this error on emulator. I have tried at unity versions 2022.3.7 and 2022.11.2. I am using the ai foundation framework and for android emulator i am using Pixel with google play services and android version 8.1 and 13.
Any ideas?